# Как удалить из всех строк символы. ,! ? " ': ” “, если в таких строках есть блеклист слово?

Tags: javascript, текст, txt, работа-с-текстом

Как удалить из всех строк символы . , ! ? " ' : ” “ , если в таких строках есть блеклист слово?

**Блеклист слова в переменной [[BLACK_LIST]] :**

```
красной
печали
```

**Список символов для удаления в переменной [[SYMBOLS]] :**

```
. , ! ? " ' : ” “
```

**Исходный текст (пример) в переменной [[TEXT]] :**

```
Ах, я вспоминаю ясно, был тогда декабрь ненастный, 
И от каждой вспышки красной тень скользила на ковер.
Ждал я дня из мрачной дали, тщетно ждал, чтоб книги дали
Облегченье от печали по утраченной Линор, 
По святой, что там, в Эдеме ангелы зовут Линор,
Безыменной здесь с тех пор.
```

**Чтоб осталось так в переменой [[TEXT]]** (удалил в 2ой и в 4ой строке) **:**

```
Ах, я вспоминаю ясно, был тогда декабрь ненастный, 
И от каждой вспышки красной тень скользила на ковер
Ждал я дня из мрачной дали, тщетно ждал, чтоб книги дали
Облегченье от печали по утраченной Линор
По святой, что там, в Эдеме ангелы зовут Линор,
Безыменной здесь с тех пор.
```

Я писал **JS-код** для удаления всей строки если в ней есть блеклист слово, но код удаляет всю строку, а мне нужно удалить **только символы . , ! ? " ' : ” “** из строк **в которых содержаться блеклист слова** (без удаления самой строки):

```
[[TEXT]] = [[TEXT]].filter(function(line){
  return [[BLACK_LIST]].every(function(forbiddenWord) {
    return line.toLowerCase().indexOf(forbiddenWord.toLowerCase()) === -1;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, Вам не следует удалять строки. Меняем `filter` на `map`, и по результату проверки отдаем или исходную строку, или строку с заменой символов:

```js
let text = `Ах, я вспоминаю ясно, был тогда декабрь ненастный, 
И от каждой вспышки красной тень, !скользила на ковер.
Ждал я дня из мрачной дали, тщетно ждал, чтоб книги дали
Облегченье от печали по утраченной Линор, 
По святой, что там, в Эдеме ангелы зовут Линор,
Безыменной здесь с тех пор.`;

let symbols = /[.,!?"':”“]/g;
let blackList = ['красной', 'печали'];

let newtext = text.split('\n').map(function(line) {
  let notFound = blackList.every(function(forbiddenWord) {
    return line.toLowerCase().indexOf(forbiddenWord.toLowerCase()) === -1;
  });

  return notFound ? line : line.replaceAll(symbols, '');
}).join('\n');

console.log(newtext);
```

Возможно и [такое извращение](https://regex101.com/r/TN80Pq/1). Не стоит воспринимать всерьез. Привел для разнообразия.